# dict_key object does not support indexing-python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error saying "dict_key object does not support indexing" at:

```
return len(G[G.keys()[0]])
```

I realised it used to work in python 2.7.x but not in python 3.How should i change this statement to make it work in python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `G.keys()` returns a list, but Python 3.x returns a `dict_keys` object instead. The solution is to wrap `G.keys()` with call to `list()`, to convert it into the correct type:

```
return len(G[list(G.keys())[0]])
```

Comment: When i try this statement,I am getting "the list out of index" error.

Comment: This happens if `G` is empty, but the same would happen on Python 2.x as far as I'm aware.

Comment: If you have Python 2.x code that you need to run with 3.x, you may want to take a look at the command [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html): it shows you what needs to be changed and how in order for the code to be Python 3.x compatible. The command should have been installed with your Python distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the objects returned by `keys`, `values`, and `items` are [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), which don't support indexing.

Try, instead:

```
len(next(iter(G.values())))
```

This gets the dictionary view object for the dictionary's values, gets its iterator, grabs the first item from the iterator (the first value in the dictionary), and returns its length.

Unlike other methods that create a new `list` of the keys or values, it should take approximately the same amount of time no matter the size of the dictionary.

It works in both Python 2 and Python 3 (though to be efficient you'd need to use `itervalues` or `viewvalues` on Python 2).

Comment: @user3258267 That'll happen if `G` is empty. If you want to default to `0`, you can use `len(next(iter(dct.values()), []))`